# Login Function VB.net using MS Access // two usertypes

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

*Hello, I am trying to create a login system wherein there will be an admin and superadmin to login, I just followed some tutorials over the net and tried it on my own, I am new to vb and I just wanna try it out. However doing the codes below, it is not either logging in. It's always going to the catch part wherein it says it doesn't connect to the database. Here is the code error btw*

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginBtn.Click

        If userBox.Text = "" Or passwordBox.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username and password are blank", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        Else
            Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ResortReservationSystem.accdb"
            Try

                Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username='" & userBox.Text & "' AND password = '" & passwordBox.Text & "'"
                Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)

                sqlCom.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()

                Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()


                If sqlRead.Item("userType") = "Admin" Then
                    MenuForm.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                ElseIf sqlRead.Item("userType") = "SuperAdmin" Then
                    EmployeeForm.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                Else


                    MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match.", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

                    userBox.Text = ""
                    passwordBox.Text = ""


                    userBox.Focus()
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database..", "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End Try

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Were you able to debug your code? Which line in the code throws exception? What's the message of exception?

Comment: You need to call `sqlRead.Read()` after defining it and before you access the Item. It would be best to do this in an If statement. If the If succeeds, then you know the username / password combination was good; if it fails, the user has mistyped. Incidentally, a couple of other things to work on: it is considered bad practice to store passwords in plain text; and although you are using MS Access, which is somewhat cushioned against SQL injection, you are still vulnerable. I realise you are just experimenting, but at some point you should also research hashing techniques and use of parameters.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya im getting error in this line
If sqlRead.Item("userType") = "Admin" Then
it says >An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No data exists for the row/column.

But I do have datas on that field

Comment: Did you read my comment?  The reason you are getting that error, is that you have not called sqlRead.Read().  This must be called before you try to access the data.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your `Or` in the first `If` statement to an `OrElse` to short circuit the code from checking the second condition if it finds the first to be True.

Connections are precious objects and need to be closed and disposed. Open as late as possible and closed as soon as possible. `Using...End Using` blocks ensure this even if there is an error. In this case the command object is also included in the `Using`.

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Likewise, pass the command text and the connection to the constructor of the command.

I changed the `Select` statement to only retrieve `UserType` because that is all that is used in the method. Don't pull more information than necessary from the database.

Learn to use `Parameters`. It makes the sql statement easier to write, speeds up the query and protects against sql injection.

Since we are only retrieving a single piece of data we can use `.ExecuteScalar` which gets the first column of the first row of the result set.

After the connection and command are closed and disposed with the `End Using`, we can deal with the data retrieved from the database.

```
Private Sub OpCode()
    If userBox.Text = "" OrElse passwordBox.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Username and/or password are blank", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim AdminType As String
    Using conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ResortReservationSystem.accdb"),
            sqlComm As New OleDbCommand("SELECT UserType FROM tbl_user WHERE username= @User AND [password] = @Password", conn)
        With sqlComm.Parameters
            .Add("@User", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = userBox.Text
            .Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = passwordBox.Text
        End With
        conn.Open()
        AdminType = sqlComm.ExecuteScalar.ToString
    End Using
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(AdminType) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match.", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        userBox.Text = ""
        passwordBox.Text = ""
        userBox.Focus()
    ElseIf AdminType = "Admin" Then
        MenuForm.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    ElseIf AdminType = "SuperAdmin" Then
        EmployeeForm.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
```